# How can one project with dependencies see changes in another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I have two solutions, Domain.TA.SupervisionPlan.API and SubDomain.Event. Domain.TA.SupervisionPlan.API depends on SubDomain.Event. After making changes to SubDomain.Event, I want Domain.TA.SupervisionPlan.API get those changes. Do I need to publish the changes in some manner, such that the dll with the changes is deployed to the appropriate folder for Domain.TA.SupervisionPlan.API to access?

Comment: How is the dependency setup? Is it a project reference, nuget reference, direct dll reference? Are all the source files in the same location (such as version control repo)?

Comment: Well this is the path in Properties, so I'm guessing nuget: C:\Users\smabry\.nuget\packages\bi.subdomain.event.api\1.2.26

Comment: It is recommended to add nuget related tags